# How to import a Jdeveloper java project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jdeveloper

I have a java project in Jdeveloper, but I want to migrate this project to a eclipse java project, Do you know how to do that?, or Do I have to import it manually?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually keywords Import... in your menu panel will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically projects have a structure if it is a web based project or a java project, it has its structure , you should be able to import your project using File -> import. There could be specific properties file that were part of JDeveloper that you may want to ignore or manually delete them before importing it.

Answer (score 1):

File/Import/Existing Projects into Workspace.

Comment: It doesn't work, because the project wasn't configured in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to make empty Java project. After that open file browser, go to workspace directory (in my computer this is under /home/biske/workspace), find this empty project and copy source from JDeveloper project into this newly created empty Java project.

Answer (score 0):

Steps, I took after some searching and seeing this answer to migrate jdeveloper application to eclipse is following :

1. Importing project as File System into WorkSpace.
2. Adding Folder... *Java Build path > Source*. for me which was folder
   public_html and src (you can rename them as per your need).
3. Add library's from application which was *WEB-INF/lib* for me.
4. Select appropriate Server for me, it was Apache version from Project
   Facets > Runtimes (also change dynamic web module, java, javascript 
   as per you need).

Now, Just solve remain compile time and run time error. that's it.

hope this is helpful