# How to transition/migrate from Jdeveloper w ADF to an alternative/elegant IDE (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, migration, oracle12c, jdeveloper

I am trying to migrate to eclipse, Intellij etc... away from Jdeveloper! I need to use most of the existing framework like ADF, Weblogic, Oracle DB. Which makes it a shame I am trying to escape from JDEV

I have managed to run some ADF items on a java ADF project set up in eclipse, but it is far to cumbersome. I am essentially just rewriting the code, and I've failed to actually migrate the far larger project/ any of the individual screens.

Can anyone give me a more detailed or effective method to migrate a larger project in Jdeveloper using the above technologies into one of these IDEs?

Note:
My end goal is to escape from the incredibly slow deployments, and constant freezing of Jdeveloper. I would happily accept methods for speeding up Jdeveloper as well, though that only postpones the future grave that JDev seems to offer it's clients.

==
Useful IDE download Eclipse w ADF:

## https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/eclipse/adf/gettingStarted/Tutorial/ADFwithOEPE_2.html

General methods for migrating(not specific, and not good for mass migration):

## https://coderanch.com/t/104431/ide/migrating-eclipse-jdeveloper

[How to import a Jdeveloper java project in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055703/how-to-import-a-jdeveloper-java-project-in-eclipse?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: I would suggest that you look into how to make JDeveloper work better for yiu. At your current level of expertise the task you are undertaking is larger than you think.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have better chance looking into how to fix your jdeveloper performance issues(there is a lot of tutorial online) than migrating to another IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible to migrate any larger ADF project to Eclipse. The OEPE package isn't maintained anymore (to my knowledge). It's not 100% (maybe 70%) function compatible to JDev. Even if you migrate small pages/aps you have to do much work by hand to make it run.

You did not tell us the exact JDev and JDK version you are using. This makes it impossible to point you to some helpful blogs, articles or threads to hopefully fix your problems.

Comment: Thank you for your responses( Andersen, Cedric, and Timo), and I apologize for the missing information. JDEV 12c is the current version of JDeveloper I am using alongside JDK8 (update up to 131). I just joined my project, and the amount of time absorbed by the stated issues are horribly ugly. As such, I wish to improve productivity for the team, and wider mission. I would greatly appreciate any further ideas, guides, and alternative methods for attacking the problem! Regardless, thank you for the input. I appreciate it

Comment: Look at https://community.oracle.com/message/15050931#15050931 which has really helpful hints on what to do. The entry is for 12.2.1.3 but most of it should work in 12.2.1.x versions too.

Answer (score 2):

A new version of [JDeveloper](http://oracle.com/jdev) and [ADF](http://oracle.com/adf) have been released.

- Blog with a quick demo - https://blogs.oracle.com/jdeveloperpm/oracle-jdeveloper-and-oracle-adf-12214-now-available
- More new features - https://www.oracle.com/technologies/developer-tools/jdeveloper/12214nf.html
- List of fixed bugs - https://www.oracle.com/technologies/developer-tools/jdeveloper/12214rn.html

In the list of the fixed bugs it says

> JDEVELOPER 12.2.1.3.0 IS VERY SLOW

Maybe the new version fixes the issue.
I haven't tried myself, yet.

Comment: This is the funniest fix ever :D You made my day man :D

Comment: I am still using 11.2.4.... :( Had too many weird bugs with the 12c version, so we didn't continue with it.